# fixed position on scrolling page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two div in site body.I want to have fixed position to the left div...
but when scrolling to bottom it comes on my contact us div..this is the sample page:http://www.runsensible.com/legal/privacypolicy
here is my code:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}

<div id="menu-privacy">
    <div class="fusion-text">
    <p>
        <a href="#info" class="_ps2id _mPS2id-h" data-ps2id-offset="">– What information we collect from you</a>
        <a href="#info-used" class="_ps2id _mPS2id-h" data-ps2id-offset="">– How your information is used</a>
        <a href="#info-shared" class="_ps2id _mPS2id-h" data-ps2id-offset="">– How your information is shared</a>
        <a href="#terms-services" class="_ps2id _mPS2id-h" data-ps2id-offset="">– Terms of service</a>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("menu-privacy").getElementsByClassName("fusion-text")[0];
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is instead of having a JavaScript function, we can use a CSS class for it. 
**NOTE:** Based on the requirements of your specification, you can vary the size of width & height. And you can put this as `class="fixed"` for the div tag containing `id="menu-privacy"` as you can see below.

```
   .fixed{ 
     position: fixed;
     top: 80px;
     right: 0px;
     width: 100px;
     height: 150px;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) give an id to footer or add a wrapper for footer section
2) let your function like this - you need to let condition by footer position

```
function myFunction() {
  if (sticky < footerIdOffset) {// footerIdOffset is an offset for footer section
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

3) you need to subtract margin/gabs between footer and upper section to work in your point truth.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use position:sticky instead so this effect can be achieved with pure CSS rather than adding javascript. Looking at your site it's rather possible to do this

Here's what you need to do

1. Remove the javascript that add/remove the sticky class
2. Add this style in your div with id="menu-privacy", something like this

### CSS

```
#menu-privacy {
   position: sticky;
   top: 80px;
}
```

note that you can play around the top value to achieve the gap that you like. Hope this helps!

Comment: `sticky` is not supported in IE

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the attribute "z-index" to the contact div.

Answer (score 0):

On "Contact Us" div set (z-index:10) .